# Error when generating Excel report in Quality Center

Tags: sql, excel, hp-quality-center

I wrote SQL code that tests fine from end to end (all possible values), but when "Generating report" to Excel, an error pops up ("" is not a valid floating point value).  In actuality, none of my values are valid floating point values, it is just a list so far.  I have post-processing off so it is not related to any macros.  How do I get past this error, what is the real problem?  The SQL is fairly simple:

```
SELECT
run1.rn_run_name,
cycle.cy_cycle,
test.ts_name,
STEP.ST_STEP_NAME,
STEP.ST_STATUS
FROM (
SELECT
*
from run
where rownum =1 order by RN_EXECUTION_DATE desc
) run1
left join cycle on cycle.cy_cycle_id = run1.rn_cycle_id
left join step on run1.rn_run_id = step.st_run_id
left join test on step.st_test_id = ts_test_id
where cycle.cy_cycle_id  is not null
and run1.rn_run_id  is not null
and step.st_test_id is not null
and  ts_test_id is not null
order by
cycle.cy_cycle,
test.ts_name,
run1.rn_run_name,
STEP.ST_STEP_ORDER
```

Comment: Could you please share the result of query?

Comment: QC doesn't let you copy and paste easily from the test query page. In looking  for a  way around  this today, found my company got and pushed an update to QC that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is fixed by ALM Patch 12.